# My jenkins jobs fails to start

Tags: 12.04, software-center, jenkins

When I try to start jenkins on my Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS I get an error

```
$ sudo start jenkins
start: Job failed to start
```

Comment: same problem... There is nothing in /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log

But I can start jenkins with `sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the installed service is broken. But it works, as stated in my comment above, when you start the server with `sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start`.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
sudo rm /etc/init/jenkins.conf
sudo update-rc.d jenkins defaults
sudo service jenkins start
```

Then....

```
root@core:/# service jenkins start
* Starting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server jenkins                    [ OK ]
```

Borrowed from: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-users/eW_yEWLojFc/tFhb8DKoRHUJ